# It there any standard way to redirect SOAP request?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, redirect

The problem is following:

1. Some client tries to access an SOAP webservce
2. Webservice implementation anylizes request and comes to conclusion that it is not able to proccess the request itself. However, the webservice knows what some additional webservice should be called instead of one.
3. ???
4. Client calls "additional webservice" like he did at step 1

It there any specific standard or technique for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the proper [HTTP status code for redirection](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection). A status of `303 See Other` comes to mind.

Comment: This is the first thing I thought about. Good solution, but looks like a hack. I'm not sure if generic SOAP client is able to understand such redirection.